# SQL Query for Loan Amortization

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a table with millions of records. I am trying to retrace how much principal has been paid toward a loan. In my table, I have loan amount, loan start date, loan end date, interest rate.

Let's say a loan is on payment 100 out of 360 with a loan amount of $10,000 and interest rate of 5%. I am trying to find how much has been paid towards principal thus far where the end product will show initial loan amount minus principal paid. And then create a process that will calculate this for the millions of records.

Is something like this feasible? Creating an amortization schedule is doable, but not sure how to do it for millions of records.

I have found examples of an amortization schedule query but it would be for only 1 loan.

Comment: So you want the schedule for all million+ loans? What are you going to do with this?

Comment: Are you just asking for the formula to calculate the present value of the loan? If you are then have you just tried googling for the formula - it’s a standard calculation available all over the web? If you aren’t then I’m not clear what you are asking?

Comment: I think the fact that you've got limited interaction with this question is a reasonable indication that what you're asking for here is not really "help with an issue", but for someone to guide you on developing a solution to a need - the latter of which StackOverflow is not really intended for.  You might possibly have some better luck at dba.stackexchange.com, but I'm not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947357/sql-server-calculate-amortization